# Is there a way to know when Linux needs keyboard input/an app is requesting it?

Tags: linux, qt, pyside6, qtvirtualkeyboard

Is it possible to know when linux/an app on linux (pyqt - qwebengine) needs keyboard input?

I am trying to build a kiosk web browser type app, which obviously needs keyboard input at some point. While the website/html document I control can send a console message (`console.log("show keyboard");`) which i can receive and then show a keyboard based on it. Is there a way to do this without this hacky approach? Which also makes it work for 3rd-party websites.

All I need to know is when keyboard input is requested/needed, the rest I can do.

It doesn't necessarily need to be done in python, so if there is an approach where I can grab some sort of syscall and show my OSK (on-screen-keyboard) or something similar of that sort, please share it as well.

The biggest issue is that the OSK can't be third-party as it needs to be specialized for the specific use case, so qtvirtualkeyboard, florence or other linux OSKs won't work.

If there is nothing like the above qtvirtualkeyboard will have to suffice, however I already tried and failed to get it working so if there is an updated tutorial on how to enable it. Please comment/post below.

Comment: *"it needs to be specialized...so qtvirtualkeyboard...won't work"* -- Qt Virtual Keyboard can be [customized](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtvirtualkeyboard-overview.html#adding-custom-layouts). If you're using Qt WebEngine for your browser, it should know to bring up the keyboard on input fields.